# PHP and sharing resources between requests

Tags: php, xml, resources, shared-memory

I'm looking for a way to share PHP resources between requests. First of all, I want to share parsed XML. I have some large XML that I use in readonly mode, and currently I have to load and parse it for each HTTP request.

I've read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shm-put-var.php and the other shared memory API documentation, and I know that there is no straight way to store resources in shared memory. That's why I ask here.

So, I have XML, I use it in readonly mode (performing XPath-requests), this XML is large, and I'm looking for some way to eliminate the need of loading and parsing it for each HTTP request. Any ideas or advices about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have APC enabled on your server, take a look at `apc_store`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.apc-store.php

> Unlike many other mechanisms in PHP, variables stored using
>   apc_store() will persist between requests (until the value is removed
>   from the cache)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions for this http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php that's what they are build for.

> As a website becomes more sophisticated, so must the code that backs
>   it. When you get to a stage where your website need to pass along user
>   data from one page to another, it might be time to start thinking
>   about using PHP sessions.

Comment: Are you sure it's good idea to keep N-megabytes XML in the session? :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and save the object or the file in memcache. Then any Webservice can load the file and work with it. Memcache is very fast and you can access it from many Webservers.